# Will this count as two pageviews in GA, and do I need the second pageview?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm having a hard time finding clear documentation on how to handle this situation and what best practise is.

**Question:**
How off is my implementation and what steps should I take to fix it? Will it count as two pageviews? Do I need the second pageview?

**Implementation**
I my head

```
<script>
  // analytics.js

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'ec');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'somevalue')
  ga('set', 'dimension2', 'somevalue')
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

on pageload in checkout

```
for (var i = 0; i < cart.products.length; i++) {
  var product = cart.products[i];

  const gaProductObject = {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
    'category': product.category
    'price': product.price,
    'quantity': product.quantity,
    'brand': product.brand
  }
  
  ga('ec:addProduct', gaProductObject)
}

if (this.user.isAuthenticated) {
  ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 2,
    'option': null
  })
} else {
  ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 1,
    'option': null
  })
}

ga('set', 'dimension1', this.user.market)
ga('set', 'dimension2', this.user.language)
ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'view')
ga('send', 'pageview')
```

Using: GA and Enhanced Ecommerce. 
Site: hybrid .NET and Vue. No Virtual Views required page do pageloads on each navigation.

Thankful for feedback.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with direct `ga()` setup to write this as an answer, but my assessment would be a) yes, you'd see two pageview hits, and b) no, you shouldn't need the second pageview because the event hit will include page and custom dimension data. For session-scope dimensions, the last value sent in the session will be the value associated to all hits of the session.

Comment: @Reve thanks for the reply. Yes I figured it out. I'm not using session based.